# Add leading zeros to colum names

Tags: r, gsub, leading-zero

I'm surprised to find no one asked this question on Stackoverflow before. Maybe it's too stupid to ask?

So I have a dataframe that contains 48 weather variables, each representing a weather value for a month. I have drawn a simplified table shown below:

| weather 1 | weather 2 | weather 3 | weather 4 | weather 5 | weather 6 | weather 7 | weather 8 | weather 9 | weather 10 | weather 11 | weather 12 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 6 | 34 | 9 | 100 | .01 | -4 | 38 | 64 | 77 | 21 | 34 |
| 99 | 42 | -3 | 34 | 34 | .5 | 27 | 19 | 7 | 18 | NA | 20 |

My objective is to make the column names from "weather 1, weather 2, ..." to "weather 01, weather 02, ...." And I wrote a loop like this:

```
for (i in 1:9){
  colnames(df) = gsub(i, 0+i, colnames(df))
}
```

However, instead of replacing the single-digit numbers with a leading zero, R replaced the actual letter "i" with "0+i". Can anyone let me know what's going on here and how to fix it? Or is there a better way to add leading zeros to column names?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use

```
library(stringr)
colnames(df) <- str_replace(colnames(df), "\\d+", 
      function(x) sprintf("%02d", as.integer(x)))
```

Comment: Holy guacamole, that's fast.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another option:

```r
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(35)
example <- tibble(`weather 1` = runif(2),
                  `weather 2` = runif(2),
                  `weather 3` = runif(2))

rename_with(example, ~str_replace(., "(weather )(\\d+)", "\\10\\2"), everything())
#> # A tibble: 2 x 3
#>   `weather 01` `weather 02` `weather 03`
#>          <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>
#> 1       0.857         0.553       0.486 
#> 2       0.0108        0.950       0.0939
```

or with base R

```r
colnames(example) <- gsub("(weather )(\\d+)", "\\10\\2", colnames(example))
example
#> # A tibble: 2 x 3
#>   `weather 01` `weather 02` `weather 03`
#>          <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>
#> 1       0.857         0.553       0.486 
#> 2       0.0108        0.950       0.0939
```

Comment: I think your regex should be `"(weather )(\\d$)"` (assuming more than 9 weather columns in case)